# Add incoming commits to pull request description

Tags: git

I wish to create a pull request describing the incoming commits. Is it possible only through the interface or must I do some coding?

My thoughts:

1. Duplicate pull request template with appended `_orig` tag;
2. Parse `git log`
3. Add some placeholders manually or programmatically on the pull request copy
4. Add parsed comments on the template without `_orig` tag;
5. Commit changes and push.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically possible, but unpractical in real life.

What if your pull-push cicle contains a few dozens of commits? Once you start implementing a new feature or upgrade versions - the number of commits can easily be in the hundreds (often with comments like: "adding X", "Removing X - bad idea", "Adding X back", "Removing X - still bad idea"). How do you expect to automate that?

The interface approach is much easier and more reliable. You can of course, reread log of commits to remind yourself what list of features/bugs were solved in them, but the final message for merge commit should come from a keyboard.

Comment: If you end up with hundreds of “adding X”, “removing X” etc. commits in a single set of changes, you could perhaps rebase the commits to produce a useful set of commits ;-). (I’m not going to say “should” because this is subjective.)